# Upload and read excel file in ExtGWT

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, upload, gxt

I am using ExtGWT. in my application i should accept **excel file** through **browse** button and should read the content of excel file and display in a grid. please suggest me how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to upload the excel document via a `FileUploadField` - See: [API](http://www.sencha.com/gxtdocs/#com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.FileUploadField) and [Example](http://www.sencha.com/examples/pages/forms/fileupload.html)

On your server you will have to read the file and parse it via an external Excel API like one of those

- [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) *(only .xls files)*
- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

Then you pass the result to your client as `List<ModelData>` and display it on your editor grid.

Be careful about the fileupload because the file is not uploaded in the same way like your regular GXT forms.

As you can see in the example you need to specify an `URL` for your form

```
panel.setAction("myurl");
```

The easiest way, would be to write a servlet for this action and process the file there like that with [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> files = upload.parseRequest(request);

// process uploaded files
```

Uploading files via `XMLHttpRequest` is unfortunately not supported by some browsers.

Comment: Hi powerMicha, Thanks for ur reply. i need one widget for browse button to submit the form and one async and interface and interface implementation. inside interface implementation i need to use POI right? are these classes sufficient or do i need to create any servlet? Please could u share me the example if u have?

Comment: Hi powerMicha, my clientserciveimpl already extends RemoteServiceServlet. still do i need to write a servlet?

Comment: Yes, I think so, because the new servlet must be mapped to another path and called via the `action` parameter of your `FormPanel` - Maybe it is possible to use your `ClientServiceImpl` with another mapping as well but I have not done this before and I think this will mess up your code